# How to Make Request XML in Xamarin Forms and use it to Read Data Xml

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms

I Want to read xml data in Xml but the problem is the url have request parameter, and that make me cant  read the xml data w. What i know is standart read data xml in xamarin forms like this

```
var document = XDocument.Load("http://www.forex.se/ratesxml.asp? id=492");
var row = document.Descendants("row").FirstOrDefault();
if(row != null)
{
   var sellCash = row.Element("sell_cash")?.Value;
   USDSellLabel.Text = sellCash;
}
```

and my Request Xml is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Request param="name" param="name" param="name">
</Request>
```

so my question is how to input that request to my code so i can get/read the xml data ?

this is the returned xml from URL when i tried in Postman

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response type="service-response">
    <ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode>
    <ResponseStatus>success</ResponseStatus>
    <ResponseMessage>
        <Accounts>
            <Account Name= 'Payments' AvBal ='0 USD' ResBal ='0.00 S$' Currency ='USD' LocalBalance ='0.00 MYR' defaultW ='false'  />
        </Accounts>
        <Accounts>
            <Account Name= 'Point' AvBal ='100 LP' ResBal ='0.00' Currency ='LP' LocalBalance ='100.00 MYR' defaultW ='false'  />
        </Accounts>

        <Accounts>
            <Account Name= 'AccountMoney' AvBal ='381000 USD' ResBal ='0.00 S$' Currency ='USD' LocalBalance ='116.08 MYR' defaultW ='true'  />
        </Accounts>


        <PdfUrl>http://123.123.123.123:7171/file?a123123.pdf</PdfUrl>
    </ResponseMessage>
</Response>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual XML text returned from URL.  You need credentials to get xml from your URL.

Comment: @jdweng I edited my question hope you can understand thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var response = doc.Elements("Response").Select(x => new
            {
                type = (string)x.Attribute("type"),
                code = (int)x.Element("ResponseCode"),
                status = (string)x.Element("ResponseStatus"),
                message = x.Descendants("Account").Select(y => new
                {
                    name = (string)y.Attribute("Name"),
                    avBal = (string)y.Attribute("AvBal"),
                    resBal = (string)y.Attribute("ResBal"),
                    currency = (string)y.Attribute("Currency"),
                    localBalance = (string)y.Attribute("LocalBalance"),
                    defaultw = (Boolean)y.Attribute("defaultW")
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```